# Rails 3 Active record validation error messages with unwanted/extra characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I'm workin on ROR app using Rails 3.2.9 and I'm getting the error messages for a sign up page in my app as follows

<li>Login is too short (minimum is 3 characters)</li><li>Email is too short (minimum is 7 characters)</li><li>Email is invalid</li><li>Password can&#x27;t be blank</li><li>Password is too short (minimum is 4 characters)</li><li>Password is invalid</li><li>Password confirmation can&#x27;t be blank</li>

These are the default messages of Active Record Validation . (ref: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html )

This app was previously written in Rails 2 and later migrated to rails 3. I have changed the validates_presence_of commands to validates : password , :presence=>true etc in accordance with rails 3 .
In the view ( signup.html.erb) error_messages_for is rendering these msgs. It is deprecated from rails 3. 
Can anyone tell me what needs to be used instead of error_messages_for in the view and  all code needs to be changed correspondingly for getting the error msgs right..

Here's the code (not complete)

user.rb in app/model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :excel_files         # One user may have many excel files
  has_one  :user_access_validity# One user may have one license period 

  # Virtual attribute for the unencrypted password
  attr_accessor :password

  attr_accessible :login
  attr_accessible :email
  attr_accessible :password
  attr_accessible :password_confirmation
  attr_accessible :company


  #changes of 'validates' in accordance with rails 3:

  validates :login,  :presence => true, 
                        :length => { :within => 3..40}, 
                        :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false },
                        :format => { :with =>  /^([a-z_0-9\.]+)$/i },
                        :on => :create, 
                        :if => :is_login_entered?
  validates :email, :presence => true, 
                        :length => { :within => 7..100}, 
                        :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false },
                        :format => {:with => /^([a-z]+((\.?)|(_?))[a-z0-9]+@(mindtree.com|rvce.edu.in))$/i},
                        :on => :create,
                        :if => :is_email_entered? 
  validates :company, :presence => true,
                        :format => { :with =>/(mindtree|RVCE)/i},
                        :format => { :with => /^([a-z]+)$/i },
                        :on => :create, 
                        :if => :is_company_entered? 
  #validates_presence_of     :login, :email, :company
 on => :create, :if => :is_login_entered?


   validates :password, :presence => true,
                       :length => { :within => 4..40 },
                       :confirmation => true,
                       :format => { :with => /^([a-z0-9@!#\$]+)$/i },
                       :on => :create,
                       :if => :password_required?



  validates :password_confirmation, :presence => { :if => :password_required? }
  #validates_presence_of     :password_confirmation,      :if => :password_required? 


  before_save :encrypt_password
```

.
.
.

In signup.html.erb

```
    <font color=red>(Fields marked * are mandatory)</font><h3>Sign me up!</h3>

    <br>


   <span class='error'><%= error_messages_for (@user) %></span>
    <%= form_for :user do |f| -%>

    <p><label for="login"><span class='redcolor'>*</span>Login</label><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :login %></p>

    <p><label for="email"><span class='redcolor'>*</span>Email</label><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :email %></p>

    <p><label for="password"><span class='redcolor'>*</span>Password</label><br/>
    <%= f.password_field :password %></p>

    <p><label for="password_confirmation"><span class='redcolor'>*</span>Confirm Password</label><br/>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></p>

    <p><label for="company"><span class='redcolor'>*</span>Company</label><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :company %></p>

    <p><%= submit_tag 'Sign up' %></p>
    <% end -%>
```

### Solution

Got the following code from  [http://www.rubydoc.info/github/edavis10/redmine/ApplicationHelper:error_messages_for](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/edavis10/redmine/ApplicationHelper%3aerror_messages_for) which shud be added in application_helper.rb and corresponding change in html.erb file as <%= error_messages_for (@user) %>

Code:

```
def error_messages_for(*objects)
  html = ""
  objects = objects.map {|o| o.is_a?(String) ? instance_variable_get("@#{o}") : o}.compact
  errors = objects.map {|o| o.errors.full_messages}.flatten
  if errors.any?
    html << "<div id='errorExplanation'><ul>\n"
    errors.each do |error|
      html << "<li>#{h error}</li>\n"
    end
    html << "</ul></div>\n"
  end
  html.html_safe
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for the question is added below the question

Comment: Why not add to this post?

Answer (score 1):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html

if you read this guide you will see that in you form you can use `form.error_messages`

Comment: Actually i want to know should any changes be made in application_helper.rb file which has the definition for the method error_messages_for

Comment: in rails 3 there is no such method in application_helper, if you have some hand-written code there i think it's better to rename it or you can delete it if it's autogenerated

Comment: I was actually working on an already developed app, i got the following code for error_messages_for from http://www.rubydoc.info/github/edavis10/redmine/ApplicationHelper:error_messages_for
and it worked

Have updated the code above